# Lebesgue measurability of a set

Tags: measure-theory

Prompted by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/intersection-of-two-huge-sets-in-the-plane) I was looking for $A \subset (0,1)$ such that for any interval $(a,b)\subset (0,1), A \cap (a,b)$ and $A^c \cap (a,b)$ are both uncountable.  One such $A$ is the set of all numbers that have a finite number of $1$'s in their base $3$ expansion.  As no choice was used in the construction, it should be Lebesgue measurable, but I can't prove it.  How is it proved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each $n$, let $A_n$ be the subset of elements of $A$ that have at least a $1$ in the first $n$ digits of their ternary expansion, but no $1$s after the $n$th digit. Your set $A$ is equal to the union of the $A_n$s and the Cantor set. Each $A_n$ is a finite union of scaled translates of the Cantor set (take $3^{-n}C$, where $C$ is the Cantor set, to get all numbers that have ternary expansion with no $1$s and that have $0$ in the first $n$ positions; then you can "translate" by adding a suitable number that has a tail of $0$s and appropriate $1$s in the appropriate coordinates).

So each $A_n$ is a finite union of Lebesgue-measurable sets (scaled Cantor sets are Lebesgue-measurable, and translates of a Lebesgue-measurable set are Lebesgue-measurable), hence Lebesgue measurable. $A$ is a countable union of Lebesgue measurable sets, hence Lebesgue measurable.

**Added.** As Andres Caicedo points out in the comments below, the argument above shows that the set $A$ is in fact not merely Lebesgue measurable, but *Borel*.

Comment: This would prove that $A$ is null, as we might expect.

Comment: Indeed it would.

Comment: @Ross, note that the description Arturo gives shows that, in fact, $A$ is *Borel* (this is much stronger than simply being Lebesgue measurable). Just about any set that you explicitly describe can be easily shown Borel by unraveling the given description: In this case, if only finitely many 1s are used, then your set is a countable union (depending on where the last 1 appears), etc.

Comment: @Andres:  Thanks.  Good point.

Answer (score 3):

The number $x_n$ in the $n^\text{th}$ place after the radix point in the ternary expansion of $x$ is a measurable function of $x$.  This is true because the floor function is Borel measurable, and $x_n=\left\lfloor 3\cdot\left(3^{n-1}x-\lfloor3^{n-1}x\rfloor\right)\right\rfloor$.  The set $\{x:x_n\neq 1\}$ is measurable for each $n$, and so therefore is the set $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty \{x:x_k\neq 1\}.$$

---

Certain null sets of the second category give further examples of this.  The complement of such a set can be contructed by taking a countable union of closed sets with empty interior whose complements have progressively smaller measure (e.g., using fat Cantor sets).

Comment: Following on Andres' comment in Arturo's answer, you have also proved the set Borel, right?  I only see countably many of the allowable operations here.

Comment: Yes, the functions involved are Borel measurable (floor is Borel, continuous functions are Borel, and compositions of Borel functions are Borel), and the inverse image of the open set $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ under a Borel map is Borel.  The Borel sets form a $\sigma$-algebra, so the countable union of countable intersections of Borel sets is Borel. (The set is even an $F_\sigma$, but that isn't as clear in my answer as in Arturo's.)  The construction of null sets of the second category I mentioned also yields Borel sets ($G_\delta$s, even).