# Measure of a function that maps rationals to $0$ and irrationals to $2^n$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a function such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $2^n$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ where $n$ is the number of zeros immediately after the decimal.
>
> Show that this is measurable.

My first idea here was that since the irrationals are a $G_\delta$ set, they are measurable.  There are countably many rationals in $[0,1]$, so that set is also measurable.  I suppose this shows that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: A function that is measurable almost everywhere is...

Comment: What you've said is not enough to establish measurability of $f$.  You need to check that $f^{-1}(2^n)$ is measurable for each $n$.  (Also, in the future it would be a good idea to make explicit your notion of measurability.)

Comment: For Lebesgue measurability it suffices to show that $f^{-1}(m,\infty)$ is a Lebesgue measurable set for every $m$. You can easily show that, up to a set of measure $0$, it is a countable union of semi-open intervals and hence measurable.

Comment: It looks to me as if the measure of any interval $[0,x]$ for any positive $x$ will be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each positive integer $n$, let $x_n$ be the digit in the $n^\text{th}$ position after the decimal point in the decimal expansion of $x\in\mathbb R$.  Then $x_n$ is a measurable function of $x$, because $x_n=\lfloor 10(10^{n-1}x-\lfloor 10^{n-1}x\rfloor)\rfloor$ is a combination of Borel measurable functions.  Therefore each set $\{x\in\mathbb R:x_n=0\}$ and its complement $\{x\in\mathbb R:x_n\neq0\}$ is measurable.  Note that for each nonnegative integer $n$, $f^{-1}\{2^n\}=(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}\{x\in\mathbb R:x_k=0\}\cap\{x\in\mathbb R:x_{n+1}\neq 0\}$ (with the convention that $\bigcap_{k=1}^0\text{stuff}=\mathbb R$).  Therefore this set is measurable.  For any $m\in\mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(m,\infty)$ is a countable union of such sets, or $\mathbb R$.

As Arturo notes in a comment, you can also describe $f^{-1}\{2^n\}$ as a countable union of open intervals with rationals removed, and this is another way to see that it is measurable.  There was a somewhat [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30770/lebesgue-measurability-of-a-set) in which I gave a somewhat similar answer while Arturo again gave a more geometric approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that $f$ is well-defined because the numbers that
have two different decimal expansions are all rationals.

Let $f_n(x) = 2^k$, where $k$ is the number of zeros from the first to the $n$-th
position after the decimal.
In order to avoid the ambiguity mentioned above, let's agree
that no decimal expansion ends in an infinite sequence of $9$.
That is, no expansion ends in $99999\dotsc$.

Then, $f_n$ is measurable.
(Why? Hint: write it as a step function.)

Now, observe that
$$
  I_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}} f_n \uparrow f,
$$
where $I_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}}$ is $0$ at the rationals and
$1$ at the irrationals.
Therefore, $f$ is measurable.

---

**Edit:** fixed the definition of $f_n$.

Comment: I don't understand. For example, isn't it true that $f_7(2.030030003000030000030000030000003…)=5$, while $f(2.03…)=2$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: In my understanding, $f(2.03\ldots) = \infty$. But I see am missing the $2^n$ part... I will fix it.

Comment: Then we have a different reading of the problem.  By "immediately", I thought it was implied that in $2.030030003\ldots$, for example, only that first $0$ counts.  $2.32344003\cdots$ has zero $0$s immediately after the decimal point, $2.00000444440000404404000\ldots$ has four, etc.  So every irrational number is sent to $2^n$ for some nonnegative $n$.  $f(\pi)=2^0=1$, but $f(\pi-0.1)=2^1=2$.   But now I understand your answer; we were just answering different questions.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: You are right. I didn't pay attention to the "immediately".